# I accidentally unplugged NodeMCU while upload an Arduino since the unable to upload anything

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-ide, nodemcu

I accidentally unplugged NodeMCU while uploading a blink sketch from Arduino IDE since then unable to upload anything, moreover my NodeMCU inbuilt LED stays on when connected to USB.

The code that I was trying to upload was just a blink sketch for inbuilt LED. It gives following error when trying to upload anything.

```
Sketch uses 247047 bytes (23%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1044464 bytes.

Global variables use 32852 bytes (40%) of dynamic memory, leaving 49068 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.

error: failed sending 0xC0
error: failed sending 8 bytes
error: failed sending 36 bytes
error: failed sending 0xC0
error: failed sending 0xC0
error: failed sending 8 bytes
error: failed sending 36 bytes
error: failed sending 0xC0
error: failed sending 0xC0
error: failed sending 8 bytes
error: failed sending 36 bytes
error: failed sending 0xC0
error: failed sending 0xC0
error: failed sending 8 bytes
error: failed sending 36 bytes
error: failed sending 0xC0
error: failed sending 0xC0
error: failed sending 8 bytes
error: failed sending 36 bytes
error: failed sending 0xC0
error: failed sending 0xC0
error: failed sending 8 bytes
error: failed sending 36 bytes
error: failed sending 0xC0
error: failed sending 0xC0
error: failed sending 8 bytes
error: failed sending 36 bytes
error: failed sending 0xC0
error: failed sending 0xC0
error: failed sending 8 bytes
error: failed sending 36 bytes
error: failed sending 0xC0
error: failed sending 0xC0
error: failed sending 8 bytes
error: failed sending 36 bytes
error: failed sending 0xC0
warning: espcomm_sync failed
error: espcomm_open failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
```

Comment: Have you tried reloading your NodeMCU's firmware with esptool?

Comment: when I tried erase flash it gives the following error:                                File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 222, in _reconfigure_port
    'Original message: {!r}'.format(ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: Cannot configure port, something went wrong. Original message: WindowsError(31, 'A device attached to the system is not functioning.')

Comment: reboot and try again. you can always use the "oh shit" button on the nodeMCU to boot into upload mode.